# Recommended order for learning design patterns?

Tags: learning, design-patterns

I can't help but notice the amount of design patterns that are out there.

Does anyone have suggestions on an order I should learn them in?  Or should I pick and choose them at random?

The only one I know, so far, is singleton.

Comment: [Head First Design Patterns](http://www.amazon.com/First-Design-Patterns-Elisabeth-Freeman/dp/0596007124/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1297158504&sr=8-1-spell)

Answer (score 20):

When you only consider the gang of 4 design patters internally at my company we have a design pattern training that has the following order, it works pretty well. Sometimes you need one to learn the other and vica versa.

Day 1

- Factory Method
- Builder
- Composite

Day 2

- Prototype
- Observer
- Facade
- Bridge

Day 3

- Abstract Factory
- Proxy
- Chain of responsibility
- Visitor

Day 4

- Singleton
- Command
- State
- Strategy

Extra:

- Adapter
- Decorator
- Flyweight
- Mediator
- Iterator
- Momento
- Template Method
- Interpreter

But when you want to learn them I would just start with the [Head First Design pattern book](http://www.bookdepository.co.uk/book/9780596007126/Head-First-Design-Patterns) (not just really my opinion, but its also seems to be the standard answer for these kind of questions) and follow that with the [gang of four design pattern book](http://www.bookdepository.co.uk/book/9780201633610/Design-Patterns). Those two together should give you all the order you need.

Comment: +1 The Head First book is a very good place to start, though I think their ordering differs slightly from yours.

Comment: Head First series are impossible to read (at least I can't) because every page is loaded with different kinds of fonts/pictures/text layout/ text size. It's like a comics.

Comment: @Sorantis agreed the head first series is not for everyone, but in general they seem to give enough context to make people remember the material better. I always tell people to first borrow a copy or go to google books to get a feel for the books http://books.google.com/books?id=LjJcCnNf92kC&printsec=frontcover&dq=head+first+design+patterns&hl=nl&ei=_n1RTdyLJ8adOrH8qMUH&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=book-thumbnail&resnum=1&ved=0CDAQ6wEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't be so concerned about learning design patterns in a specific order.

In my opinion, here are the first two steps that you should take when learning design patterns:

1. Read '[Head First Design Patterns](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596007124)'.
2. Watch the '[Questpond Videos](http://www.questpond.com/demo.html#dp)'.

Comment: +1 for Questpond, did not know that one.

Answer (score 2):

[Dofactory](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx) has a very nice organization of design pattern, including the UML diagrams as well as sample code. They also have `Frequency of use` scale, which identifies how popular the pattern is. So, I'd suggest you to browse their webpage.